# Book where a boy's dad doesn't want his son to go to the magic school he did

Tags: story-identification, books, magic

I don't remember much but there was this boy who found it hard to fit in; not many people liked him because of one of his legs. His dad didn't let him learn magic because of what is mother said before she died. The boy was sitting in front on the office of his school for is dad, his dad came and drove them to some place I don't remember.

When they got to the place the boy had to go in a room with other kids to take a magic test. The boy didn't do good on the test and was relieved he won't go to the school but the staff still made the boy go to teach him more magic and the dad wasn't happy, the dad lost the argument with the staff and took the boy to the school.

Comment: Its been while since I read that book and I really liked it thank you for tell me what is called again

Comment: What was it about one of his legs that caused people not to like him?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[The Iron Trial](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/20578940-the-iron-trial) by Holly Black and Cassandra Clare.

[image]

> All his life, Callum has been warned by his father to stay away from magic. To succeed at the Iron Trial and be admitted into the vaunted Magisterium school would bring bad things. But he fails at failing. Only hard work, loyal friends, danger, and a puppy await.

The scene at the principal's office is:

> Callum fidgeted in the stiff chair in front of the principal’s office, wondering if he’d be back at school tomorrow and if anyone would miss him if he wasn’t. Again and again, he went over all the various ways he was supposed to mess up on the mage’s test — ideally, as spectacularly as possible. His dad had listed the options for failure again and again: Make your mind totally blank. Or concentrate on something that’s the opposite of what those monsters want. Or focus your mind on someone else’s test instead of your own.

And as you say Callum has a bad leg:

> When he was wearing jeans like this, you couldn’t tell there was anything wrong with his leg, but you could sure tell the minute he stood up and started walking. He’d had surgery after surgery since he was a baby, and all sorts of physical therapy, but nothing had really helped. He still walked with a sliding limp, like he was trying to get his footing on a boat that was rolling from side to side.